# Delphi: Create a form «by hand»

Tags: delphi

I write the module:

```
unit Unit2;
interface
uses Forms;
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
  end;
implementation
end.
```

In the button OnClick handler I write:

```
with TForm2.Create(Self) do
try
  ShowModal;
finally
  Free;
end;
```

Pressing the button throws exception:

```
Resource TForm2 not found
```

Is it possible to somehow (maybe a hack) to create forms entirely «by hand», without involvement of the mechanism of saving of forms properties in resources???

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this myself, but from what I've read, there are a couple of approaches:

- Don't inherit from `TForm`, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8595468/25507)
- Use [`CreateNew`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.CreateNew), as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16113916/25507)